# Failed to install Rails on yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I installed Ruby via `rbenv`. Currently, my pc has ruby `2.1.2p95` version installed. I have just started development in rails. So, don't know much about it. 
But, I get some kind of error when I installed it.

```
 $gem install rails -v 4.2.0
 ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
         cannot load such file -- zlib
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
         undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `rbenv rehash` after installing that version of ruby? Perhaps your PATH is pointing to the wrong `gem` command?

Comment: after running rbenv rehash i am still getting that error

Comment: i have this path in my bash_profile

#Ruby export
`export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv`
`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

Comment: It tells you to add the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` thing, not sure about the rest of it, maybe that's what's getting in your way. Why don't you add that stuff to your question so you can format it properly. Seems like it could be part of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into something similar.
Try

```
xcode-select --install
```

Than perhaps give this a go if it still doesn't work:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1.2p95
rbenv install 2.1.2p95
```

Comment: commandline tools, xcode, brew everything is installed in my pc. Also, i have tried other versions as well same error.

Comment: but strange when i write this command `rbenv uninstall 2.1.2p95` it says....`rbenv: version 2.1.2p95 not installed`